# How does Grails MongoDB plugin handle polymorphism?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, polymorphic-associations

I have an object like the following:

```
class User {
    static mapWith="mongo"
    static embedded = [ 'profiles' ]

    String email
    List<Profile> profiles;
}

interface Profile {
}

class Profile1 implements Profile {
}

class Profile2 implements Profile {
}
```

If I add the concrete classes Profile1 or Profile2 to the User object and save it to the database it throws an exception when reading that object back out of MongoDB.  I don't see any information being saved to the DB to identify which type of object it should instantiate in this situation.  And there is exactly ZERO documentation about how this case is handled.  Other frameworks have mechanisms for handling this so either Grails MongoDB is woefully broken, or this is just undocumented (again).  So how do I fix this?

The exception is the following:

```
| Error 2013-06-12 18:48:00,390 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - InstantiationException occurred when processing request: [POST] /mpa/user/authenticate -parameters:

  email: carhubb@gmail.com
  password: ***
  com.mycompany.security.Profile. Stacktrace follows:
  Message: com.mycompany.security.Profile
  Line | Method
  ->>  342 | newInstance0                        in java.lang.Class
  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
  |    310 | newInstance                         in     ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual answer is that grails seems to handle classes but not interfaces which is truly bizarre because if you handle polymorphism for classes it's trivial to handle it for interfaces because you can handle it the same way.  But if you use classes for all reference types it will add a special '_class' property to mongodb and it will use that to instantiate the object of the actual reference the object pointed to when it was saved.  Now how hard was that to explain in one paragraph rather than trolling through pages of source code and unit tests?

Comment: Where do you have your interface? Which directory?

Comment: It's under src/groovy.  You can't put interfaces under grails-app/domain because grails tries to add methods to it.  It's very hard to figure that out when it happens too.  The error message is not clear what happened.  I guess if you aren't going to solve the full problem documentation is important, but if it just works out of the box I'd be less harping on docs.  The real problem(s) is grails just doesn't work out of the box in some very common situations and doesn't document anything enough to where we can solve it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Grails MongoDB is not at all broken and every use case might not get documented. :)
Your use case works fine as expected and successfully tested as shown below.

```
// src/groovy
interface Profile {
    Integer getDuration()
}

import org.bson.types.ObjectId
class Profile1 implements Profile {
    ObjectId id
    String profileName
    String type
    Date effectiveStartDate
    Date effectiveEndDate

    Integer getDuration(){
        effectiveEndDate - effectiveStartDate
    }

    static mapWith = "mongo"
}

import org.bson.types.ObjectId
class Profile2 implements Profile{
    ObjectId id
    String profileName
    String type
    Date effectiveStartDate
    Date effectiveEndDate

    static mapWith = "mongo"

    Integer getDuration(){
        effectiveEndDate - effectiveStartDate
    }
}
class User {
    ObjectId id

    static mapWith = "mongo"
    static embedded = ['profiles']

    String email
    List<Profile> profiles
}

class UserController {

    def index() {
        def profile1 = new Profile1(type: 'Individual',
                                    profileName: 'IndividualProfile',
                                    effectiveStartDate: new Date(),
                                    effectiveEndDate: new Date() + 100) as Profile
        def profile2 = new Profile2(type: 'Company',
                                    profileName: 'CompanyProfile',
                                    effectiveStartDate: new Date(),
                                    effectiveEndDate: new Date() + 50) as Profile

        println profile1.duration //prints 100
        println profile2.duration //prints 50

        def user = new User(profiles: [profile1, profile2], email: 'abc@gmail.com').save(flush: true)

        render user as JSON
    }
}

//db.user.find()
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("51ba8d55892cb98368b2f1e5"), 
    "email" : "abc@gmail.com", 
    "profiles" : [{   
            "effectiveEndDate" : ISODate("2013-09-22T03:26:13.396Z"),   
            "effectiveStartDate" : ISODate("2013-06-14T03:26:13.396Z"),   
            "profileName" : "IndividualProfile",    
            "type" : "Individual" 
        },
        {   
            "effectiveEndDate" : ISODate("2013-08-03T03:26:13.423Z"),       
            "effectiveStartDate" : ISODate("2013-06-14T03:26:13.423Z"),   
            "profileName" : "CompanyProfile",
            "type" : "Company" 
        } 
    ], 
    "version" : 0 
}
```

You can also find the above setup [here](http://pastebin.com/8vFpEgYC).

*Note:-* For simplistic usage `Profile1` and `Profile2` is designed alike.

Comment: How does mongodb know to instantiate Profile1 vs Profile2 based on the type field?  Is that documented what the behavior of that is? Is it a magic field name with special meaning assigned to it?  Wouldn't it be better if type was filled in automatically (rather than forcing the user to do it)?  I've wasted so much time trying to find anyone talking about this, and there is nothing.  Most of the information out there seems is just confusing as to if its even supported.  Grails is super disappointing in the documentation department (and unit tests aren't docs).

Comment: Why does `mongodb` need to know which Profile to instantiate? Your application has to take care of it. Can you provide the detail design of interface and implementation of `Profile1` and `Profile2`? Moreover, we need to come out of the `waterfall` world and try to cope up with `Agile`. TDD makes it easier and effective to treat Unit Test cases as documents. If there was no one talking about the problem, then dig into source code in github and try tracking the issue, if any. The driving factor for open source software is CONTRIBUTION from its users.

Comment: Fine how does my application have to take care of instantiating it?  Poor documentation is poor documentation in agile or waterfall.  It has nothing to do with process.  I'm in the process of working through the source code, but that takes significantly more time and involvement than quickly reading documentation.  Plus source code isn't indexed very well by search engines which are primarily optimized for documentation NOT unit tests.  When I search for this stuff there are zero unit tests that come up.  What we need is stick to the practicalities and not opine platitudes about process.

Comment: @dmahapatro would this work if Profile1 and Profile2 had different properties ? Will grails give me back the proper profile class ? just like it would have done if it was hibernate - using hibernate inheritance mapping